# How to remove comma from string 1,398.90 using groovy

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I am not able to remove comma from string 1,398.90 using groovy

def liveprice = '1,398.90';
def liveprice2 = liveprice.replaceAll(',', '')

Comment: your code works fine. please provide the details why you can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would really avoid using regular expressions with numbers

Especially numbers that look like money

You can use DecimalFormat to read that String into a BigDecimal (so you keep precision)

```
import java.text.*

BigDecimal result = DecimalFormat.instance.with {
    parseBigDecimal = true
    parse('1,398.90')
}
```

Comment: in groovy please.

Comment: That is Groovy... 

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @daggett, your code works fine. Another alternative way besides regex or replace:

```
'1,39,9,,,,.90'.split(",").join()
// outputs: 1399.90
```